# Identifying Length of Date Gap Given List of Dates

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a script that searches a list of dates, and identifyies how long date gaps are.  I'm new to VBA, and this may be completely wrong, but after referencing several sites, here is what I came up with:

```
Sub IdentifyGaps()

Dim startdate As Date 'first date in column
Dim enddate As Date 'last date in column
Dim ust As Date 'first date of unemployment
Dim i As Long
ust = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value

With Sheet6
    startdate = [A1]
    enddate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value

    For i = startdate To enddate
        If ust <> DateAdd("d", 1, i) Then
            Sheet6.[C1].Value = DateDiff("d", i, ust)
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

I'm not receiving an error, but the macro is not working properly.  Right now, it's returning -43074 when it should be returning 15.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of the data, with the lone date gap it should pick up.

[image]

Comment: Try using `enddate = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value` instead of Row

Comment: You have a variable - `b` - that isn't defined in what you provided, which throws an error (on my side, at least). Can you please provide a visual of your worksheet data so we can better understand how its structured?

Comment: @xthestreams thank you - that did enable the macro to work; however, the value given was "-43074", which means that it's not working properly yet.

Comment: @TotsieMae you're right! I apologize, I edited my code and missed that.  "b" should be "ust".  I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub IdentifyGaps()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Date1 As Long, Date2 As Long, Gap As Long, lRow As Long

Set ws = Sheet6
lRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Date1 = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
    Date2 = ws.Cells(x + 1, 1).Value
    Gap = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)
    If Gap > 1 Then
        ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = Gap
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End If
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my calendar, I believe your expected result should actually be 17, not 15. This code will return the gap value as a `Long` value with which you can do whatever you want.

```
'Reads a column of dates and returns the length of the first gap found
Function IdentifyGaps() As Long
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date

    'This Variable is not needed for this solution, it is instead replaced by Gap
    'Dim ust As Date
    Dim Gap As Long

    'Read cell values into an array for more efficient operation
    Dim ReadArray() As Variant
    ReadArray = Sheet6.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = UBound(ReadArray, 1)

    StartDate = ReadArray(1, 1)
    EndDate = ReadArray(LastRow, 1)

    'ThisDate and PreviousDate are declared explicitly to highlight program flow
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim ThisDate As Date
    Dim PreviousDate As Date
    For Row = 2 To UBound(ReadArray, 1)
        ThisDate = ReadArray(Row, 1)
        PreviousDate = ReadArray(Row - 1, 1)
        Gap = ThisDate - PreviousDate
        If Gap > 1 Then Exit For
        Gap = 0
    Next Row

    IdentifyGaps = Gap
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ProveIt()
    Debug.Print IdentifyGaps
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan!  I just tried this and it seemed to work the first time, but the second time I got a Type Mismatch error at 'ReadArray=Sheet6.Range("A1").CurrentRegion', the only difference being that I was on Sheet1 when I ran it, which is what will happen when this workbook is used.  I don't know enough to know if that's the issue, but if so, what would I need to change to allow the script to run effectively regardless of the active sheet?

Comment: @khelm `ActiveSheet` is the object the represents the Worksheet that is currently active. It has all the same properties and methods as any other `Worksheet` object (although in my experience IntelliSense does not recognize it as such, so won't autocomplete for you).